# Castle interface proxy with a dynamic target

Tags: c#, signalr, signalr-hub, castle-dynamicproxy

I am trying to use Castle DynamicProxy to implement a typesafe version of a SignalR Hub.
The goal being when I use Clients.All rather than getting a dynamic object back I have an interface to use.

The code is rather hacky at the moment but I wanted to prove that it will work before I go through the trouble of making it nice:

```
public interface IChatClient
{
    void broadcastMessage(string name, string message);
}

public class ChatHub : TypeSafeHub<IChatClient>
{
    public void Send(string name, string message)
    {
        Clients.All.broadcastMessage(name, message);
    }
}

public abstract class TypeSafeHub<TInterface> : Hub where TInterface:class
{
    public new TypeSafeHubCallerConnectionContext<TInterface> Clients
    {
        get
        {
            return new TypeSafeHubCallerConnectionContext<TInterface>(base.Clients);
        }
    }
}

public class TypeSafeHubCallerConnectionContext<T> where T:class
{
    private IHubCallerConnectionContext context;
    private ProxyGenerator proxyGen;

    public TypeSafeHubCallerConnectionContext(IHubCallerConnectionContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
        proxyGen= new ProxyGenerator();
    }

    public T All
    {
        get
        {
            return proxyGen.CreateInterfaceProxyWithTarget<T>(context.All);
        }
```

Right now when I'm returning the proxy it fails because the target does not implement the interface.

Is there an easy way to achieve this goal or should I look at using an InterfaceProxyWithoutTarget and using an interceptor to wire up the call to the dynamic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be on the right track.

This is a feature slated for release in SignalR 2.1. You can look at how it is implemented here: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/commit/3c4b8794b0f512daec677110a8e41ac717514584

While there is likely a way to do this with Castle DynamicProxy, it might be simpler to use [ImpromptuInterface](https://github.com/ekonbenefits/impromptu-interface#readme).

Every call made to [`TypedClientBuilder<T>.Build(_dynamicContext...)`](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/commit/3c4b8794b0f512daec677110a8e41ac717514584#diff-15) could be replaced with `Impromptu.ActLike<T>(_dynamicContext...)`. In your case, the call to `Impromptu.ActLike` would replace `proxyGen.CreateInterfaceProxyWithTarget`.

If you feel really adventurous, you can try out the [SignalR nightlies from MyGet](https://www.myget.org/gallery/signalr) which already have the feature included.

Comment: OK so if I'm understanding correctly I would only need to use the ImpromptuInterface solution if I use Signal R 2.0. If I used the nightly or waited until 2.1 I'd be covered?

Comment: Hub<T> *should* be in SignalR 2.1. I don't believe than any release date has been announced yet.

Comment: That's fine, this was meant more as a proof of concept than actual functionality, the fact that its being done at all has me pretty excited. I will be able to revisit the other interface proxying that I've posted about on SO and clean it up as well.